# Android dependency not updating in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, dependencies

I have two projects in Eclipse, one is Android Java, the other is regular Java. The regular Java is a dependency of the Android one. Specifically, I'm using libGDX to make an Android game.

If I change something in the regular Java project (which is all the time), I have to go through hoops to make the Android project update. I either manually clean the Android project all the time, or have to "modify" it by adding/deleting random new lines so that it updates.

This is incredibly frustrating and a supreme waste of time - it also isn't an issue for non-Android projects. How do I fix this?

Eclipse Version: Indigo Service Release 2

Comment: Can you make your java project a sub project of android? I think you can clean and build on save for one project. But It will not build another project.

Comment: The desktop version of the game does get updated, so there must be a mechanism to allow the Android project to do the same. The problem persists when I only have the Android and normal Java projects.